# Can't draw on Picturebox

Tags: c#

Suppose we have a Form an a picturebox on it:

Where is the problem? Rectangle disapears on picture box. Why?

```
   private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50));

    }
```

Comment: Firstly use `e.Graphics` from the supplied `PaintEventArgs` instead of creating a new `Graphics` object.

Comment: Why are you writing `Everlasting` above all your questions?

Comment: @deltreme: I'm not a hundred percent sure, but isn't that the answer? The rectangle is painted on another `Graphics` object then the rest?

Comment: thanks all . yes i should replace e.graphics .

Comment: everlasting makes me to remember the everlasting God.

Comment: @Parkhid: You mind stopping that? `Hi` and `Thank you` is already considered as unnecessary noise...

Comment: @Bobby: I didn't even realise it would fix the problem, just thought it would help work toward the solution.

Comment: @deltreme: I didn't test it, but it sounds logical that this might be an issue. Because the `Graphics` object which you get with the EventArgs is only 'borrowed' from the control.

Answer (score 1):

I checked it and yeah the case is what everybody mentioned in comments.

The problem is that you are not taking the reference of  Graphics when painting instead just pushing your Rectangle in picturebox's graphics which wont be rendered.

To get it right you will need to use `e.Graphics` to get a refrence on the graphic that is going to be painted.

So correct code is:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50));

}
```